# Как изменить права на исполняемый файл через Android Shell ( adb shell )

Tags: android-sdk, g++, android-ndk, android

Мне необходимо запустить **hello world** написанный на C++ и откомпилированный при помощи **Android toolchain 9**, но я столкнулся с тем что по-умолчанию у меня нет прав запускать приложение, а поменять я их почему то не могу командой **chmod**.

Я использую **Android 2.3.3 - Api Level 10**

При компиляции использовался toolchain для **API level 9**

Порядок действий:

Откомпилировал программу:

> ~/toolchain_andr9/bin/**arm-linux-androideabi-g++**
> **helloworld.cpp**

Затем записываю результат на карту памяти эмулятора:

> **adb push a.out /mnt/sdcard**

Затем перехожу в SHELL на эмуляторе и пытаюсь запустить программу:

> **adb shell**
>
> **/mnt/sdcard/a.out**

И получаю результат:

> **`/mnt/sdcard/a.out: permission denied`**

команда ls -l показывает слежующие права на мой **a.out**:

> **`----rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw   863656 2012-04-12 22:42 a.out`**

Как видно владелец не имеет прав на запуск, поэтому я пытаюсь разрешить это:

> **chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard/a.out**

Однако права **не меняются**:

> **`----rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw   863656 2012-04-12 22:42 a.out`**

Мне кажется я упустил какую-то важную деталь при работе с Андройдом.

Кто-нибуть, подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно запустить подобное приложение используя **Android SHELL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо перемонтировать карту. [Build and run C application on Android](http://my.opera.com/otaku_2r/blog/build-and-run-c-application-on-android). Что-то вроде:

```
mount -o remount,rw -t vfat /dev/block//vold/179:0 /sdcard
```

потом уже

```
chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard/a.out
```